Multidimensional version of Regulated Integral
In Serge Lang's Real and Functional Analysis he introduces the regulated integral for functions of one variable. It seems like it should be possible to extend this to $n$-variables by considering step functions on $k$-cells, i.e. product of half open interval.
Has anyone developed this theory, or is it necessary to use Lebesgue integration?
